# Scrollable content in the middle of a modal dialog with variable height sticky header on top and footer with position absolute at the bottom?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, dialog

I have the following Bootstrap 3.x modal dialog:

```
<!-- Modal dialog -->
<div class="modal fade in" id="dlgUsr" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="dlgTitle">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dlg-full-haw" role="document">
     <div class="modal-content" style="height: 100%;">
        <div class="modal-dlg-drag-bar"></div>
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
          <h3 id="dlgTitle" class="title">Title</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
         <? require 'some_server_generated_code.php'; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default">Close</a>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSaveUsr">Save</a>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>           
</div>
```

The div with id `modal-body` contains server generated HTML code. And here is the CSS:

```
.modal-dlg-full-haw .h1, 
.modal-dlg-full-haw .h2,
.modal-dlg-full-haw .h3, 
.modal-dlg-full-haw h1, 
.modal-dlg-full-haw h2,
.modal-dlg-full-haw h3 {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.modal-dlg-full-haw {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;    
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin: 10px;
}

.modal-dlg-full-haw .modal-content {
    height: 100%;    
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
 }

.modal-dlg-full-haw .modal-header {
    padding: 0 15px 0 15px;
}

.modal-dlg-full-haw .modal-footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.modal-body .tab-content {
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.modal-content .modal-dlg-drag-bar {
    height: 15px;
    cursor: -webkit-grab; cursor: -moz-grab;
}
.modal-content .modal-dlg-drag-bar:active {
    cursor: -webkit-grabbing; cursor: -moz-grabbing;
}
```

Now, here is the rendered code (with the server side part too):

```
<div class="modal fade in" id="dlgUsr" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="dlgTitle" style="display: block; padding-right: 15px;">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dlg-full-haw" role="document">
     <div class="modal-content" style="height: 100%;">
        <div class="modal-dlg-drag-bar"></div>
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
          <h3 id="dlgTitle" class="title">User</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="tabbable">
    <form action="#" method="post" id="formUsr" class="formo">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="tabUsr">
            <li class="active"><a href="#tabGen" data-toggle="tab">Tab 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabRuo" data-toggle="tab">Tab 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabGdo" data-toggle="tab">Tab 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabSog" data-toggle="tab">Tab 4</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">

            <div class="tab-pane active" id="tabGen">                
              <input type="hidden" id="usr_id" value="2">
                  <div class="">
                     <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="usr_nick">Nick</label>
                        <input type="text" value="" id="usr_nick" class="validate[required] form-control" name="usr[nick]">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="usr_pwd">Password</label>
                        <input type="text" value="" id="usr_pwd" class="validate[required] form-control" name="usr[pwd]">
                    </div>
                </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="">
                     <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="usr_last_name">Last Name</label>
                        <input type="text" value="" id="usr_last_name" class="form-control" name="usr[last_name]">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="usr_first_name">Name</label>
                        <input type="text" value="" id="usr_first_name" class="form-control" name="usr[first_name]">
                    </div>
                </div>
                  </div>
                <div class="">
                     <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                      <label class="control-label" for="usr_email">E-Mail</label>                            
                      <input type="text" value="" id="usr_email" class="form-control" name="usr[email]">                             
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                      <label class="control-label" for="usr_tel">Telephone</label>                                                
                             <input type="text" value="" id="usr_tel" class="form-control" name="usr[tel]">
                    </div>              
                </div>
                  </div>                
            </div>







        </div>
    </form>
</div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default">Close</a>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSaveUsr">Edit</a>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>           
</div>
```

It looks like this:

[image]

If I resize the height of the browser's window:

[image]

You can see that the dialog's footer overlaps with the modal-body. Here is another screenshot:

[image]

How can I make that `modal-body` (which contains the tabs and the form with inputs) scrollable while maintaining the CSS I already have and the footer sticky at the bottom with position absolute as I have already done?

Comment: You could try `display flex`: http://jsfiddle.net/109ffbuj/2/

Comment: I have tried it, didn't work. Isn't there a way to do it using CSS's old stuff? Or at most JS?